# Trying to convert array of strings to date

Tags: powershell, datetime, date-formatting, datetime-parsing

I'm running into a weird issue where I'm trying to parse an array of the following strings, which have been given the variable `$DatesUnformatted`:

```
2020-02-28T05:29:00Z
2020-02-28T04:52:00Z
2020-02-28T04:52:00Z
2020-02-27T17:01:00Z
2020-02-27T17:01:00Z
2020-02-27T17:01:00Z
2020-02-27T17:01:00Z
```

...to a time format (`hh:mm tt`) using `[DateTime]::ParseExact()`.

My script looks like something like this:

```bsh
foreach ($DateUnformatted in $DatesUnformatted)
{
    $DateFormatted = [datetime]::parseexact($DateUnformatted, 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ',$null).ToString('hh:mm tt')
    echo "Converting $DateUnformatted to $DateFormatted"
}
```

And here's the output:

```
Converting 2020-02-28T05:29:00Z to 12:29 AM
Converting 2020-02-28T04:52:00Z to 11:52 PM
Converting 2020-02-28T04:52:00Z to 11:52 PM
Converting 2020-02-27T17:01:00Z to 11:52 PM
Converting 2020-02-27T17:01:00Z to 11:52 PM
Converting 2020-02-27T17:01:00Z to 11:52 PM
Converting 2020-02-27T17:01:00Z to 11:52 PM
```

It seems like it's only converting the first few entries then just repeating one until the end of the loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hh` only works for *12*-hour time formats (with AM/PM designators), whereas your input uses *24-hour* format, for which you must use `HH`:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact(
  $DateUnformatted, 
  'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ', # note the 'HH'
  $null
).ToString('hh:mm tt')
```

Your symptom implies that `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` was in effect, otherwise you would have seen the `ParseExact()` method trigger its statement-terminating errors loudly, with error messages such as:

```
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String '2020-02-27T17:01:00Z' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

Either way, the last *successful* call's result lingered in variable `$DateFormatted`.

Comment: Looks like my comment got deleted after submitting an edit. Yes you are correct that the $ErrorActionPreference was set to 'SilentlyContinue.' The actual script is using an API to grab events that may or may not contain a date string so I was getting a lot of errors. Not ideal when printing the stdout/stderr to an Ansible playbook run. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can also just implicitly convert strings to datatime like this:

```
([datetime]'2020-02-28T04:52:00Z').ToString('hh:mm tt')
```

Full code:

```
$DatesUnformatted | foreach { "Converting $_ to " + ([datetime]$_).ToString('hh:mm tt') }
```